# in mysql how to print like this : only in one query

Tags: mysql

> I have an employee table

[image]

> and what I want is **salary < 6000** is convert into one column and
>   **salary > 6000** convert into another table ...like this

[image]

> I try this: not generate the proper result

[image]

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN salary <  6000 THEN salary END) salary_less_then_6000, 
    (CASE WHEN salary >  6000 THEN salary END) salary_gerater_then_6000 
FROM employee
```

*hope you understand what I want. any help is appreciable*

Comment: It's possible to achieve what you're looking for, but it's gonna be complicated and tricky because with purpose to achieve such result you have to have clear join rule, and this rule not clear, and this rule may vary depending on count of salaries < 6000 and > 6000 (not clear which table to join to another, lt_6000 to gt_6000 or gt_6000 to lt_6000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do achieve this is to create two tables, one with salaries < 6000, and the other with salaries >= 6000, and then `JOIN` them. Now since there is no natural ordering in these tables, we have to create an artificial row number for each table and then `JOIN` them based on that. Since we don't know which table may have more rows, we have to do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support that, so we have to emulate it with a `LEFT JOIN` `UNION` with a `RIGHT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e1.salary AS salary_less_then_6000, e2.salary AS salary_greater_then_6000 
FROM (SELECT salary, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum
      FROM employees
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum1 := 0) r
      WHERE salary < 6000
      ORDER BY salary
      ) e1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT salary, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum
      FROM employees
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r
      WHERE salary >= 6000
      ORDER BY salary
      ) e2
ON e1.rownum = e2.rownum
UNION
SELECT e1.salary AS salary_less_then_6000, e2.salary AS salary_greater_then_6000 
FROM (SELECT salary, @rownum3:=@rownum3+1 AS rownum
      FROM employees
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum3 := 0) r
      WHERE salary < 6000
      ORDER BY salary
      ) e1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT salary, @rownum4:=@rownum4+1 AS rownum
      FROM employees
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum4 := 0) r
      WHERE salary >= 6000
      ORDER BY salary
      ) e2
ON e1.rownum = e2.rownum
```

Output (from my demo)

```
salary_less_then_6000   salary_greater_then_6000
3000                    7000
5000                    8000
(null)                  9000
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/edf81d/5)

Comment: Add 1 more row in your table `('e', 9000)`, will this query work correctly?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak good pickup - need a FULL OUTER JOIN. Now if only MySQL had one... back to the drawing board

Comment: @VladimirKovpak now emulating a FULL OUTER JOIN so query works regardless of which table has more entries.